# Как вернуть полный url UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Делаю запрос через UIWebView и после загрузки запроса, я хочу чтоб в getTokenString возвращался полный url, а в место этого возвращается обрезанный вариант. например: [http://сайт.com](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.com) ,а мне нужен полный : [http://сайт.com/кракозябра](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.com/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0)

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewInstantSafari
{
    NSString *getTokenString = self.webViewInstantSafari.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"%@", getTokenString); //печать в консоль
}
```

Может есть и другие способы вывести полный url ? Почему этот вариант не работает так как надо?

Answer (score 1):

Верно было бы так:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViewInstantSafari
{
    NSString *getTokenString = webViewInstantSafari.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSLog(@"%@", getTokenString); //печать в консоль
}
```

в своём примере вы читаете свойство класса, а не переданное делегатом.